# Чтение примера и подстановка значений вместо неизвестных

Tags: java, javafx

мне необходимо считать пример, не важно с консоли или через формы javafx, а затем вместо неизвестного x, подставить какое-то значение. Не знаю как это сделать, пробовал парсить строку, но так как там есть символы по-типу "*","/","^" этого сделать не удалось. Буду рад любой помощи. Заранее спасибо. Примерно вот такие строки я читаю "x^2-6*x+14".

Answer (score 0):

Читайте про [RPN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)
Считываете операнды в один стек, операторы в другой, при вычислении, если операнд - переменная, ищете (скорее всего в мапе) чему она равна и подставляете. Ну и вычисляете выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Нагумнокодил тут немного, но ты сам просил любой -))

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "x^2-6*x+14";
    str = str.replaceAll("x","2"); //подставляем вместо икса двойку, например
    String outStr = "";
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    int i = 0;
    while (true){
        try{
            if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
                outStr += str.charAt(i);
            }
            else {
                if(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)).matches("[\\-+*/\\^]")){
                    outStr += " ";
                }
                if(str.charAt(i) == '('){
                    stack.push(str.charAt(i));
                }
                else if(str.charAt(i) == ')'){
                    while (true){
                        if(stack.peek() == '('){
                            stack.pop();
                            break;
                        }else {
                            outStr += " "+stack.pop();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    while (!stack.empty() && stack.peek() != '(' && getPriority(stack.peek()) >= getPriority(str.charAt(i))){
                        outStr += stack.pop() + " ";
                    }
                    stack.push(str.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            i++;
        }catch (Exception e){
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!stack.empty()){
        outStr += " " + stack.pop();
    }
    System.out.println("Polish: " + outStr);

    String[] polish = outStr.split(" ");
    Stack<Double> stack1 = new Stack<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < polish.length; j++){
        try {
            stack1.push(Double.valueOf(polish[j]));
        }catch (Exception e){
            double b = stack1.pop();
            double a = stack1.pop();
            stack1.push(calculate(a, b, polish[j].charAt(0)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Answer: " + stack1.pop());
}

private static int getPriority(char c){
    switch (c){
        case '^': return 4;
        case '*': return 3;
        case '/': return 3;
        case '+': return 2;
        case '-': return 2;
        case '(': return 1;
        case ')': return 1;
        default: return 0;
    }
}

private static double calculate(double a, double b, char operation){
    switch (operation){
        case '^': return Math.pow(a, b);
        case '*': return a * b;
        case '/': return a / b;
        case '+': return a + b;
        case '-': return a - b;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

}